# Rails 3.2.8:Ошибка при развертывании приложения на heroku

Tags: windows, github, ruby-on-rails

Создал пустое приложение и закинул его на `github`: https://github.com/andrebatist/event. Создал и записал на репозиторий `SSH`-ключ, вроде бы все сделал как надо. Закинул тот же ключ на свой аккаунт `heroku $ heroku keys:add`, создал ссылку:

```
mighty-gorge-6970
```

На команде

```
$ git push heroku master
```

вышла ошибка:

```
 -----> WARNING: Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
 Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
 This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
 -----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.0.pre.5
 Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin
 Installing sqlite3 (1.3.7)
 Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
 checking for sqlite3.h... no
 sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
 or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
 location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
 *** extconf.rb failed ***
 Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
 necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more
 details. You may need configuration options.
 An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
 Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 ! Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 ! Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

 To git@heroku.com:mighty-gorge-6970.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
 error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:mighty-gorge-6970.git'
```

Я не знаю почему он не видел `sqllite`, я раньше его устанавливал, может, установка помощника `heroku` для `windows` все испортила?

Comment: Вы используете RoR на Windows? (извините за холивар, чисто ИМХО) Это извращение.

Comment: Да.А что в этом такого?На линукс и масОС рельсы ставить ничуть не проще...Суть-то все равно одна.

Answer (score 1):

Хероку использует только PostgreSQL.
В Gemfile нужно заменить 'sqlite3' на 'pg' и отредактировать файл conf/database.yml

PS: При геренарции проекта можно указать какую базу вы хотите использовать.

```
rails new app -d postgresql
```

Либо можно использовать скулайт в депелопменте, а постгри в продакшене:

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Comment: Группа development находится в gemfile? я добавпил туда :
[CODE]source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'pg' 

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
[/CODE]
Но все равно выходит та же ошибка...Я не понимаю,ни в одном учебнике про это не сказано

Comment: В Gemfile можно определить каике гемсы будут загружаться в определённой среде (env). Будь то production или dev.

ps: Покажите ваши Gemfile и database.yml через pastie.org или gist.github.com :D